# RTSP stream to ffmpeg problems

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, rtsp, ip-camera, openrtsp

I'm writing a web application for managing and viewing streams from ONVIF ip-cameras.
It's written in nodejs. The idea is to run a child process in node and pipe output to node, then send the buffer to client and render it on canvas. I have a working solution for sending data to client and rendering it on canvas using websockets but it only works on one of my cameras.

I own 2 IP cameras and both of them have rtsp server.
One of them(let's name it camX) kind of works with this ffmpeg command (sometimes it just stops, maybe due to packet losses):

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -re -i <rtsp_link> -f mjpeg pipe:1
```

But the other one(camY) returns `Nonmatching transport in server reply` and exits.

I discovered that the camY transport is `unicast` but ffmpeg doesn't support this particular lower_transport as I read on ffmpeg forum.

So I started looking for a solution. My first idea was to use `openRTSP` which works fine with both streams.
I looked at the documentation and came up with this command:
`openRTSP -4 -c <rtsp_link> | ffmpeg -re -i pipe:0 -f mjpeg pipe:1`
`-4` parameter returns stream to pipe in mp4 format
And here's another problem I ran into, ffmpeg returns:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x559a4b6ba900] moov atom not found  
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Is there any way to make this work?
I tried various solutions I found, but none of them worked.

**EDIT**

As @Gyan suggested I used `-i` parameter instead of `-4` but it didn't solve my problem.

My command:

```
openRTSP -V -i -c -K <rtsp_link> | ffmpeg -loglevel debug -re -i pipe:0 -f mjpeg pipe:1
  
Created receiver for "video/H264" subsession (client ports 49072-49073)
Setup "video/H264" subsession (client ports 49072-49073)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err 29)
Outputting to the file: "stdout"
[avi @ 0x5612944268c0] Format avi probed with size=2048 and score=100
[avi @ 0x56129442f7a0] use odml:1
Started playing session
Receiving streamed data (signal with "kill -HUP 15028" or "kill -USR1 15028" to terminate)...
^C
[AVIOContext @ 0x56129442f640] Statistics: 16904 bytes read, 0 seeks
pipe:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

As you can see openRTSP command return err 29 but in meantime it outputs some data to pipe.
When I terminate the command ffmpeg shows that it read some data but couldn't process it.

Here's the function that produces that error:

```cpp
void AVIFileSink::setWord(unsigned filePosn, unsigned size) {
  do {
    if (SeekFile64(fOutFid, filePosn, SEEK_SET) < 0) break;
    addWord(size);
    if (SeekFile64(fOutFid, 0, SEEK_END) < 0) break; // go back to where we were

    return;
  } while (0);

  // One of the SeekFile64()s failed, probable because we're not a seekable file
  envir() << "AVIFileSink::setWord(): SeekFile64 failed (err "
          << envir().getErrno() << ")\n";
}
```

In my opinion it looks like it won't be able to seek file because it's a stream not a static file.
Any suggestion for a workaround?

Comment: ffmpeg needs the MOOV header to parse the data, and this header is typically written once all media data has been processed. Try outputting to AVI in OpenRTSP.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66280861/1207193) might help you, it seams the ffmpeg problem related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things here:

1. `Nonmatching transport in server reply` - this is most likely not due to unicast (because unicast is the normal way - sending the stream to a single client). The error most likely comes from the fact, that you are actually forcing RTP over TCP with the `-rtsp_transport tcp` flag. You have several options here - check the cameras which are not working, check if they are set to only UDP and set them to TCP, or even better - do not force the transport and let ffmpeg negotiate with the camera. Maybe this solves the issue at once.
2. Regarding OpenRTSP - The `moov` atom is usually written at the end of the file when all the needed data is known, and since you are piping it, it actually breaks the logic here. I would assume OpenRTSP actually never emits the `moov` since it never ends the stream and thus ffmpeg never gets it. I would advise to simply try and fix the RTSP transport as stated above.